# JSON as message exchange format

Tags: json, avro

When two programs, irresepective of the language they are implemented in, want to exchange messages, they can do so with a common format such as protobuf, or avro. For this, they use tools such as proto3 or avro-tools to generate class structures in multiple languages that can be used by the producer and consumer programs.

If my message format needs to be JSON, is there a way I can achieve the same thing? Can I use a compiler to generate classes that will emit and consume JSON when serialized and deserialized?

I am saying JSON because I need the messages to be human-readable in addition to being program exchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger are a very good tool to create and document REST APIs:

http://swagger.io/

It support the creation of server and client files in many languages.